Basic matrix multiply question
Just a sanity check, seems like this is valid, but I haven't seen this formula used/mentioned. Suppose $C=AB$ and let the columns of $A$ be $a_i$ and rows of $B$ be $b_j^T$, then can we claim $C = \sum a_ib_i^T$?
I manually checked some entries and this seems to hold, I'm just surprised I cannot find people mentioning it.

Yes - matrix multiplication is a sum of rank-1 outer products.

As for "people mentioning this": I seem to remember that this is given as one possible way of thinking of matrix multiplication in Gilbert Strang's Introduction to Linear Algebra. This can also be seen as an instance of block-matrix multiplication.

You might also note that if the columns of A are unit vectors then $a_I a_i^T$ is a projection. A symmetric matrix can be diagonalized and rewritten as a combination of such projections, a finite dimensional version of the spectral theorem.

Thanks for the references and confirmations. @BenGrossmann thank you for the block matrix reference, this is something I specifically struggle with intuitively. Any references on how to think in terms of blocks when reasoning about matrix multiplication and other operations? I sort of think of blocks as individual entries when doing the algebra, but would appreciate further help. Thanks

@Baron You might find my explanation here to be helpful
